# How to print the values that are stored in the array using pointer and function in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am new to the pointer in c, I have done the following simple array programme using the pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void disp(int *);
void show(int a);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int marks[]={55,65,75,56,78,78,90};
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        disp(&marks[i]);
    return 0;
}
void disp(int *n)
{
    show((int) &n);
}
void show(int a)
{
    printf("%d",*(&a));
}
```

I want to get all these values that are stored in the array as output but I only get the memory number of these stored value in the array. plz, help me how to get the array values as output.

Comment: Casting `int*` to `int` but why? And `*&a` will try to print the address,

Comment: you mean i<7 to print all the members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to play with pointers.

Please note that `void show(int a)` expects `int` value.
Therefor you do not have to do anything to `a` to print it.
  `*(&a)` is equivalent to `a`. `&a` gets the address of `a` and `*` dereference the pointer.

Of course it is possible that  pointer entering `disp(int *n)` is passed down the road and dereferenced later.  This is ilustrated by calling `show1` function inside `disp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void disp(int *);  //  function disp receives the address on int value 

void show(int a);
void show1(int *a); // function show1 will receive the address of n

int main()
{
    int i;
    int marks[]={55,65,75,56,78,78,90};

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)  // 7 since you want to print all elements

        disp( &marks[i] );

    return 0;
}

void disp(int *n)
{
    show(*n); // show expects the 'int' value therefore we have to dereference the pointer. 
    show1(n); // function show1 will receive the address of n and will dereference the pointer inside the function
}

void show(int a)
{
    printf("%d ",a);
}

void show1(int *n) // show1 gives the output of the value that is stored in address n
{
    printf("%d\n",*n);  // dereference the address n to print the value
}
```

Output:

```
55 55
65 65
75 75
56 56
78 78
78 78
90 90
```

Comment: But I want to send the address of n to function show and function show will receive the address of n and give the output of the value that is stored in address n @sg7

Comment: @SourodipKundu Sure, you can do that. I have added `show1` which will take a pointer and it will dereference it for printing.

Answer (score 0):

`&` always gives you the memory address of the variable. So `&n` is giving you the memory address of the variable `n`.

If you want the value of a pointer, use `*`. To get the value stored by the pointer `n`, you want to use `(int)*n`. Of course you don't need the cast at all, just `*n`.

I recommend going over some tutorials in C/C++ pointer basics. Pointers are a basic skill you want to have a solid foundation of.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to print all the elements of that array, you just need to do

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    printf("%d", marks[i]))
```

Note that there are 7 elements in `marks`, the exit condition in the loop should be either `i<7` or `i<=6` and not `i<6`.

---

You are sending the address of a variable to the function `disp()` as `n`.

The `n` in `disp()` acts similar to a local variable of that function except that it gets its value from the function calling it.

So `n` is stored somewhere in the memory and hence has an address. This address is what you get when you do `&n`.
So what you see is probably meaningless (because they are allocated on [stack memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)).

You do an explicit type cast to `int` on this address with `(int) &n` whose value you then pass to `show()`. Read about explicit type casting [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

In `show()`, you first take the address of `a` with `&a` and then find the value in that address with    `*(&a)` which is the same thing as `a` (think along the lines of -(-a) ie, taking the negative of a number whose negative is in turn found which is the same number you started off with).

Answer (score 0):

&--> get me the address.

*--> get me the value at that address

disp(&marks[i])--> get the address of variable "marks[i]" and pass it to *n(disp(int *n)), so that when *n is executed it will get the value at the address it has been assigned.

show((int) &n)--> get address of the variable that stores the address of the variable marks[i].

To make it work as intended, it must be show(*n)--> pass the value at the address pointed to by n.
(Typecasting is not needed as you're passing an int value to show())